# How to refresh a textarea's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

There is a **third party**'s page with textboxes that break lines when texts are too long and automatically resize themselves **vertically** when that happens.

And I **created a Chrome Extension** that resizes existing textareas **horizontally**, making them smaller.

Normally, these textareas get resized automatically as one types, but when my code resizes them **horizontally**, their text might break line, and when that happens **they don't resize vertically**.

Nevertheless, if I start typing, they will resize normally.

How do I make them resize automatically after my own horizontal resize without having to change their text?

---

Javascript or Jquery answers are welcome :)

Comment: Did you try just triggering the `change` event on those textareas to see if they'll update

Comment: Tried `$("textarea").trigger("change");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: But thanks for the tip!!! After trying some of them, the `input` event works :)

Comment: And curiously, the Chrome Extension doesn't do the work in this specific case (I wonder why). I had to create a script element in the page just for that....